# aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientConnectorError: Cannot connect to host stackoverflow.com:443 ssl:default [Connect call failed ('151.101.193.69', 443)]

Tags: python, python-3.x, asyncio, aiohttp, pythonanywhere

В мой код:

```py
import asyncio
from aiohttp import ClientSession


async def main():
    url = "https://stackoverflow.com/"

    async with ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(url) as resp:
            print(resp.status)

asyncio.run(main())
```

если я запускаю его на своем компьютере, все работает, но если я запускаю его на pythonanywhere, я получаю эту ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/0dminnimda/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 936, in _wrap_create_connection
    return await self._loop.create_connection(*args, **kwargs)  # type: ignore  # noqa
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1017, in create_connection
    raise exceptions[0]
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1002, in create_connection
    sock = await self._connect_sock(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 916, in _connect_sock
    await self.sock_connect(sock, address)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 485, in sock_connect
    return await fut
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 517, in _sock_connect_cb
    raise OSError(err, f'Connect call failed {address}')
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connect call failed ('151.101.193.69', 443)
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_c.py", line 39, in <module>
    asyncio.run(main())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/runners.py", line 43, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 608, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "test_c.py", line 28, in main
    async with session.get(url, timeout=30) as resp:  # , headers=headers
  File "/home/0dminnimda/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 1012, in __aenter__
    self._resp = await self._coro
  File "/home/0dminnimda/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 480, in _request
    conn = await self._connector.connect(
  File "/home/0dminnimda/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 523, in connect
    proto = await self._create_connection(req, traces, timeout)
  File "/home/0dminnimda/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 858, in _create_connection
    _, proto = await self._create_direct_connection(
  File "/home/0dminnimda/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 1004, in _create_direct_connection
    raise last_exc
  File "/home/0dminnimda/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 980, in _create_direct_connection
    transp, proto = await self._wrap_create_connection(
  File "/home/0dminnimda/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 943, in _wrap_create_connection
    raise client_error(req.connection_key, exc) from exc
aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientConnectorError: Cannot connect to host stackoverflow.com:443 ssl:default [Connect call failed ('151.101.193.69', 443)]
Unclosed client session
client_session: <aiohttp.client.ClientSession object at 0x7f25a71d1a90>
```

aiohttp на хостинге:

```
Name: aiohttp
Version: 3.6.2
Summary: Async http client/server framework (asyncio)
Home-page: https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp
Author: Nikolay Kim
Author-email: fafhrd91@gmail.com
License: Apache 2
Location: /home/0dminnimda/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages
Requires: chardet, async-timeout, multidict, yarl, attrs
Required-by:
```

aiohttp на моём ПК:

```
Name: aiohttp
Version: 3.6.2
Summary: Async http client/server framework (asyncio)
Home-page: https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp
Author: Nikolay Kim
Author-email: fafhrd91@gmail.com
License: Apache 2
Location: c:\users\asus\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages
Requires: async-timeout, attrs, chardet, yarl, multidict
Required-by:
```

Я в недоумении, что это не так? Я запускаю оба файла с помощью python3.8.
Я также пробовал другие URL, с ними такая же проблема

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Решение #1

Добавить `trust_env = True` при создании клиента:

```py
import asyncio
from aiohttp import ClientSession


async def main():
    url = "https://stackoverflow.com/"

    async with ClientSession(trust_env=True) as session:
        async with session.get(url) as resp:
            print(resp.status)

asyncio.run(main())
```

Бесплатные учетные записи на PythonAnywhere должны использовать прокси для подключения к общедоступному Интернету, но `aiohttp` по умолчанию не подключается к прокси, доступному из переменных среды.
Но если же `trust_env` задан как `True`, тогда `aiohttp` пытается использовать прокси из переменных среды.

[Ссылка на документацию по aiohttp](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_reference.html#aiohttp.ClientSession) (cмотрите параметр с именем "trust_env")

## Решение #2

Также возможно то, что домен, к которому вы пытаетесь получить доступ не содержится в [белом списке](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/whitelist/).

В таком случае вам нужно [начать новую тему/ветку на форуме pythonanywhere](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/forums/start_topic/) с просьбой добавить домен в белый список.
Если это api, вам нужно будет предоставить ссылку на документацию для этого api.